# Get items whose maximal values of nested field less than a parameter value

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have following mapping in elasticsearch:

```
"mappings": {
  "company": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "employee": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "age": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to know if it was possible to get all of companies whose maximal values of employees age are less than 30. In SQL i just need to select company while joining employee and group by company id and make a where clause that max value of age less than 30.

Comment: Are you creating one document per employee in ES, or one document per company with multiple employees in the employee field?

Comment: I have one document per company with multiple employees!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case this is easy.  Since you will never get duplicate company's back because you only have document per company, you can just do straight search.  Example:

```
GET yourindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {"range": {
          "employee.age": {
            "gt": 30
          }
        }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It's worth noting, that if you ever want to do searches that combine employee fields you may run into issues.  For example if you want to search for all companies that have an employee with `age < 30 AND gender=MALE` this model will break down.  By default **ElasticSearch** treats all fields as independent.  That means that query would return any companies that had at least one employee that was MALE and one employee that was under 30 years old.  You would have no way to say they must be the same person.  If you need to do these types of queries, you will need to look at **nested** mappings and queries, which would change the query above a little bit.

**Details:**
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html

Comment: I needed nested query but your recommend did help me so much. So i accepted the answer!

Comment: If you need the nested query, don't forget you also need to mark the field as "nested" instead of "object" in the mapping before you index any data